# Sharing a folder only over a particular network interface

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-firewall

Is it possible to set up sharing on just one network card?  I want to share a folder or two only on my wired connection, but not my wireless connection.

I couldn't find any resources online to do this, and I'm wondering if there might be some sort of firewall configuration to do this.

Comment: If you run Samba on Windows you can limit which IP addresses it listens on:  http://www.smithii.com/samba/

Comment: I would try this, but it's currently not an option.

Comment: This had to be crossed off my list.  Too bad samba is even more of a risk than sharing files across all interfaces and wireless when the goal is to share through a single ethernet link to the other computers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open Control Panel, and then Network And Sharing Center. Go to Change Adapter Settings. Right-click the network adapter for which you do not want to share files, and choose Properties. Uncheck File and Printer Sharing.  That will disable that service for that network card while leaving it enabled for others.

Comment: You're welcome. Just an old trick from the Dial-Up Networking days of Windows 9x.

Comment: I just want to point out that this is a drastic solution that doesn't work when one wants to share some folders over one of the network interfaces and some other folders over some other network interface.

Comment: But that's not what OP asked.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed to be reminded about.  This will allow me to share with other PCs while not worrying as much about the WiFi interface.  Thank you from June 2018.