# How to share windows folders with only specific interfaces

Tags: windows-7, networking

Not enough point to keep on commenting on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/358293/sharing-a-folder-only-over-a-particular-network-interface/778989)  where someone asked how to share a windows folder over a particular network interface and the answer was to disable sharing on the other interfaces.

My question is, is there a way to share some folders over one network interface and some other folders over some other network interface?